# Is rpart randomizing the variables it tries as splits?

Tags: r, cart, rpart

I am fitting a decision with rpart on R. I have many variables and it seems to me that it would take a long time for rpart to try them all at every step, to determine what the next best split is. However, I could not find any information on whether rpart is somehow using a (random?) subset of variables. I agree that this would produce differents trees at every run and that would be weird, but at the same time I feel like trying all variables every time would take forever.

Does anyone know more about how rpart figures what the next best split is?